# How to get AppName() BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to call `getApplicationName()` in some way in Blackberry?

Answer (score 4):

try this.

```
String moduleName = ApplicationDescriptor
                .currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationDescriptor appDesc = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getName();
```

You should use getName. It is possible that the module name may not reflect the actual app name. If you created a project and refactor(renamed) it, you can have module names with the original title, even though you have an app name that has changed.